# ULogd2.x - Documents - IPFIX data generation

Tags: iptables

I would like to generate IPFIX data from the packets that are coming to my local system as part of experimentation. It seems ULogd is a good tool to do that. I am able to capture PCAP data. But there are very less documents available on ULogd2.x about IPFIX format data generation.(There are very few examples provided in ulogd.conf).

Can you provide me any links that describes about how to generate IPFIX data using ulogd2.x? 
1) What are the options available? I saw there is polling interval configuration. But I have no idea how does it work?

2) If I set hash_enable = 0, and uncomment the polling_interval value, I'm getting an exception as NFCT plugin requires hash table, evne though I have specified hash_buckets and hash_max_entries. Could you help on this?

3) In general, I would like to know how NFCT plugin works in ulogd2.x. I sent mail to ulogd mailing list, but there are no replies.

Could you shed some light?

Comment: I have a project to collect `nf_conntrack_netlink` data and aggregate it centrally, but if an efficient solution based on `ulogd` exists I'd love to hear about it!

Comment: Could you briefly describe about your project? Any links you have to do that work?

Comment: Unfortunately it'd have to be more complete then go through a code review before I can publish it. I don't target any IPFIX support on the machines but would rather take care of that centrally as I want a minimal communication layer on the hosts that can adapt to different types of information. I'll do the deduplication given I'll see many connections multiple times (from both machines when within my infrastructure, through 1 firewall in some contexts, through 2 firewalls for many cross-DC connections), and IPFIX tooling can't be as precise as some information will be lost in the translation.

Comment: [follow up] I would use `libnetfilter_conntrack` in 2 separate processes: 1. to grab all the events I'm interested into (multiple contexts to allow for complex filtering logic as their `bsf` usage is rather limited) and publish them on a `zeromq` socket, reencoded in `msgpack` (obviously with network endianness). 2. to periodically go through all connections and publish a `snappy`-compressed `msgpack`ed list. That way I can have a good view of the current connections on a host even if the other process dies, or connections are started before it, and get traffic counters reasonably often.

Answer (score 1):

Without `ulogd`, if you have CPU cycles to spare and not too much traffic, you might want to look into [fprobe](http://fprobe.sourceforge.net/).

They also have an `fprobe-ulog` fork which seems to do something very similar to your goal, but I've tried it or heard anything about it.

Comment: Thank  you, fprobe-ulog seems to be giving NetFlow information. IPFIX is the standard version of NetFlow. I would like to go with IPFIX.

Comment: Duh. IPFIX is a superset of Netflow v9. http://www.plixer.com/blog/netflow/what-is-ipfix-vs-netflow-v9/